# PHP variable not accessible until halfway through code

Tags: php, pointers, joomla, reference, joomla-k2

I am trying to access data by:

```
echo 'Item = '.$this->item->title;
```

However, I'm only able to access this data after line 124 in my code:
http://www.codeshare.io/fW9ZJ

You can see my attempt to access that data on line 33 and 123. Neither return a value. However, the same code at lines 125 and 376 do.

Why isn't the data accessible? (Note: this is part of a Joomla! K2 template file: category.php).

Comment: Where does $this->item come from? It does not appear to be defined by the time you get to lines 33 and 123.

Comment: Did you try printing the data inside the view.html.php?

echo "<pre>" . print_r($this->item) . "</pre>";

Comment: @Tom, The ouput of print_r in view.html.php yields "1". Output of that code in category.php is the same everywhere above line 124. If I add it to the foreach loop below line 124, the entire contents of the array is ouput for each item.

Comment: @bobdye, you can see $this->item being referenced on line 68. I just enabled that section of code and it is working fine. I did a few more tests and if line 68 executes, then the line above will work as early as line 69.

Comment: Right. The line above will only work **after** $this->item is defined, which make sense.

Comment: I can access that data by $item->title prior to line 68 as long as I add the following line of code before it: foreach($this->secondary as $key => &$item);
What would be the best way to define $item for reference without running this empty loop?